# Does anyone know is there a way to remove next button in flutter survey kit package?

Tags: flutter, survey

[image]https://pub.dev/packages/survey_kit

I use this above flutter survey kit. By any chance, does anyone know how to remove next button thing. Instead, I wanna use it like going to next question without having a next button. Is there a way to do it? If there is, I do appreciate it if you could help.

I read their documentation and it does not mention at all. The photo is from their package.

Comment: you can fork the package from GitHub and make changes according to your needs.